# Line Chart within row group expands in preview

Tags: reporting-services

I have designed a line chart which appears within a row group and appears for each row in the report.
But in preview the chart height changes and looks expanded.
Pls help thanks in advance

Chart in Row 1 is rendered correctly
Chart in Row 2 is rendered expanded

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUWtk.png

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information to help you with this issue.  Could you provide some images of the issue at hand and a bit more detail?  Also, check out [mre] for more tips on improving your questions.

Comment: I have attached the chart image.